# How To Change this HTTP request to HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, android, apache, http

Since org.appache is deprecated in Android 5.1.1 , and they suggest to use HttpUrlConnection .

Could you help me to change my code this , with valid HttUrlConnection command (im new in Android)

```
package com.example.cbmedandroid;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    b.setClickable(false);
    new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
}

private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {
    protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity) throws    IllegalStateException, IOException {
        InputStream in = entity.getContent();
        StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
        int n = 1;
        while (n>0) {
            byte[] b = new byte[4096];
            n =  in.read(b);
            if (n>0) out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
        }
        return out.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://192.168.43.13:8000/api/horaire.json");
        String text = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getLocalizedMessage();
        }
        return text;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
        if (results!=null) {
            EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit);
            et.setText(results);
        }
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        b.setClickable(true);
    }
}
}
```

Thanks

Also , getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity) seems to be deprecated to !

EDIT : This is what i have changed in my code .

```
  protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://192.168.43.13:8000/api/horaire.json");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader isw = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = isw.read();
            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                data = isw.read();
                System.out.print(current);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

But what about the "LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask " method ?

Comment: What had you tried already? There is plenty examples of `HttUrlConnection` usage

Comment: i changed my http connection request , im not sure if it's correct though , but i dont know how to change the getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity) method .

Comment: aside from not returning a string from the characters you read, `isw.read()` slows down the process because you read character by character. Use the `read(char[])` method with a large enough buffer to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a HttpGet request without setting anything (like an `Accept: application/json` header, choosing an encoding, ...) should be fairly equivalent to this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return get("http://192.168.43.13:8000/api/horaire.json");
}

private String get(String urlString) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlString).openConnection();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        try {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            char[] cbuf = new char[8192];
            int read;
            while ((read = reader.read(cbuf)) != -1) {
                writer.write(cbuf, 0, read);
            }
            return writer.toString();
        } finally {
            reader.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks , but what about  the LongRunningGetIO method ? do i need to change something ?

Comment: @KaneSamba no. `LongRunningGetIO` and it's `String doInBackground(Void... params)` method behave as they did before.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
StringBuffer response_string = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(params.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        os.close();



        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

        System.out.println("PostParseURL "+url);
        System.out.println("PostParseCODE " + responseCode);

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response_string.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 return response_string.toString();
}
```

and yes there are no need to `getASCIIContentFromEntity` method and here params are the Your `JSONObject` request